# Python, mechanize, trying to cope with select and checkbox controls

Tags: python, html, webforms, mechanize

I'm trying to fill a rather complex web form with mechanize and get an error.
I do the following:

```
from mechanize import Browser
url = 'some_url_here'

br = Browser() # going around robot.txt 
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_equiv(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]

br.open(url) # opening the website I need

# here I did some work studying html and finding the forms I need

br.select_form(nr=0)    # I need the first form and here the controls I need
print br.form.controls[2].name, '           type=', br.form.controls[2].type
print br.form.controls[4].name, '         type=', br.form.controls[4].type
print br.form.controls[6].name, '         type=', br.form.controls[6].type
print br.form.controls[7].name, '         type=', br.form.controls[7].type
print br.form.controls[9].name, '      type=', br.form.controls[9].type

out:
okato            type= select
grvdtov          type= select
viddata          type= select
god_chk          type= checkbox
period_chk       type= checkbox

# and here where I'm trying to select what I need and fail:

br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form.controls[2] = ['Российская Федерация']  # selecting values I need
br.form.controls[4] = ['Все товары и услуги', 'Базовый индекс потребительских цен'] 
br.form.controls[6] = ['в % к предыдущему месяцу'] 
br.controls[7].items[0].selected=True # ticking the checkbox
br.controls[9].items[0].selected=True 
reponse = br.submit()   # submitting
```

And here the error that I get:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-70-c173bbf420d3> in <module>()
      5 br.controls[7].items[0].selected=True
      6 br.controls[9].items[0].selected=True
----> 7 reponse = br.submit()

C:\Users\Asus\Anaconda3\envs\Python2\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_mechanize.pyc in submit(self, *args, **kwds)
    539 
    540         """
--> 541         return self.open(self.click(*args, **kwds))
    542 
    543     def click_link(self, link=None, **kwds):

C:\Users\Asus\Anaconda3\envs\Python2\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_mechanize.pyc in click(self, *args, **kwds)
    528         if not self.viewing_html():
    529             raise BrowserStateError("not viewing HTML")
--> 530         request = self.form.click(*args, **kwds)
    531         return self._add_referer_header(request)
    532 

C:\Users\Asus\Anaconda3\envs\Python2\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_form.pyc in click(self, name, type, id, nr, coord, request_class, label)
   2997         """
   2998         return self._click(name, type, id, label, nr, coord, "request",
-> 2999                            self._request_class)
   3000 
   3001     def click_request_data(self,

C:\Users\Asus\Anaconda3\envs\Python2\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_form.pyc in _click(self, name, type, id, label, nr, coord, return_type, request_class)
   3190         try:
   3191             control = self._find_control(
-> 3192                 name, type, "clickable", id, label, None, nr)
   3193         except ControlNotFoundError:
   3194             if ((name is not None) or (type is not None) or (id is not None) or

C:\Users\Asus\Anaconda3\envs\Python2\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_form.pyc in _find_control(self, name, type, kind, id, label, predicate, nr)
   3144             if type is not None and type != control.type:
   3145                 continue
-> 3146             if kind is not None and not control.is_of_kind(kind):
   3147                 continue
   3148             if id is not None and id != control.id:

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'is_of_kind'
```

Can anyone please tell me where I go wrong and how I can fix it?
Thank you!